# Refactoring a Private Utility Method in Java

Tags: java, junit, java-stream, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor two private methods in Java which are essentially the same thing. I am currently doing some JUnit test assertions on soccer tiebreakers and have written up a utility method which streams through results and brings back total goals scored or conceded by a team. They are very similar:

```
    private Integer getTeamGoalsScored(final LeagueTable leagueTable, final Team team) {
        return leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getHomeTeam().equals(team))
                .map(Result::getOutcome)
                .map(Outcome::getGoalsScoredByHomeTeam).reduce(0, Integer::sum) +
                leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                        .filter(t -> t.getAwayTeam().equals(team))
                        .map(Result::getOutcome)
                        .map(Outcome::getGoalsScoredByAwayTeam).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }

    private Integer getTeamGoalsAgainst(final LeagueTable leagueTable, final Team team) {
        return leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getHomeTeam().equals(team))
                .map(Result::getOutcome)
                .map(Outcome::getGoalsScoredByAwayTeam).reduce(0, Integer::sum) +
                leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                        .filter(t -> t.getAwayTeam().equals(team))
                        .map(Result::getOutcome)
                        .map(Outcome::getGoalsScoredByHomeTeam).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }
```

As you can see they are basically boilerplate, I'm wondering how to merge these two to become one method. I'm guessing a boolean for true/false, scored/against?

Comment: Which are the signatures of `Outcome::getGoalsScoredByHomeTeam` and `Outcome::getGoalsScoredByAwayTeam` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract functions that do filter and map. And pass them as parameters in this function:

```
private Integer getSum(final LeagueTable leagueTable, 
   Function<Result, Boolean> filterFun, Function<Outcome, Integer> mapFun 
) {
        return leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                .filter(filterFun)
                .map(Result::getOutcome)
                .map(mapFun).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }
```

Then you can use is in your code like this:

```
private Integer getTeamGoalsScored(final LeagueTable leagueTable, final Team team) {
    return getSum(leagueTable,
            t -> t.getHomeTeam().equals(team), Outcome::getGoalsScoredByHomeTeam) + 
           getSum(leagueTable,
            t -> t.getAwayTeam().equals(team), Outcome::getGoalsScoredByAwayTeam);
}
```

#### UPDATE

As it was mentioned in comment with `ToIntFunction` and `Predicate`; `getSum` can be written in this way:

```
private Integer getSum(final LeagueTable leagueTable, 
   Predicate<Result> filterFun, ToIntFunction<Outcome> mapFun 
) {
        return leagueTable.getAllResults().stream()
                .filter(filterFun)
                .map(Result::getOutcome)
                .mapToInt(mapFun).sum();
    }
```

Comment: You can change `Function<Outcome, Integer>` to `ToIntFunction<Outcome>` and replace `.map(mapFun).reduce(0, Integer::sum)` with `.mapToInt(mapFun).sum()`

Comment: ..and quite possibly `Function<Result, Boolean> filterFun` with a `Predicate<Result>`